# how to save and load abstract javascript variable data?

Tags: javascript, node.js, memory

I have a javascript variable, that I want to save and load if I ever close the page. I realize there is techniques like cookies or local storage, but the problem is the data is complex and likely can't be serialized into a string. it may have properties who values are functions or something. I guess what i'm asking for is something like suspending and resuming a virtual os, which preserves everything.

Does anyone know if it is possible to do with javascript or node.js?

Thanks

Comment: Not really possible across browser restarts, but persistent data shouldn’t include functions. Why are they present in your case?

Comment: why would you need to serialize the functions? sounds more like you have an instance of a class and need to be able to serialize the data and rehydrate the instance using the serialized data

Comment: seem like something that can be accomplished through https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File_and_Directory_Entries_API/Introduction What kind of data are we talking about that cannot be serialized ?

Comment: The data is the object in this library http://cs.stanford.edu/people/karpathy/reinforcejs/ for machine learning. The agent variable is a complex data that contains the weight information. The library doesn't seem to have a export/import function so it feels like I lose the data if I close the page.

Comment: Everything can be serialized into string, you just need to find right way. i.e. figure out how to deal reference cycle, how to deal with function (`fn.toString()` is enough most of the time), how to deal with class object (`obj.constructor.toString()`)